# How to Replace a string containing %2b to + using Java?

Tags: java, utf-8

I have a string "demo%2buser". I need to convert that '%2b' to '+' . i.e demo+user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, I see these `%2b` and other `%` related values in URLs. So, searched for URL decoder, the following should help

```
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.URLDecoder;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;

public class Main
{
    public static String decodeValue(String value) {
        try {
            return URLDecoder.decode(value, StandardCharsets.UTF_8.toString());
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException ex) {
            throw new RuntimeException(ex.getCause());
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String encodedValue = "demo%2buser";

        // Decoding the URL encoded string
        String decodedValue = decodeValue(encodedValue);

        System.out.println(decodedValue);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
demo+user
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look to the class `java.net.URLDecoder`; it provides the proper functionality for your purpose.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `replaceAll()` method.

```
String input = "demo%2buser";
input = input.replaceAll("%2b","+");
System.out.println(input);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do a `String::replace()` like this-

```
String s = "demo%2buser";
s = s.replace("%2b", "+");
```